# Arrange soccer fixtures with correct home - away alternation for each team

Tags: combinatorics, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to do as the title says. I have 10 teams in the same group. Every team must play the rest once each but each of them will always alternate home and away. This means that if they play at home their first game, the second MUST be away, the third home, away, home, and so on.

I tried like this:

```
1st round
0   vs. 9
1   vs. 8
2   vs. 7
3   vs. 6
4   vs. 5

2nd round   
8   vs. 0
7   vs. 1
6   vs. 2
5   vs. 3
9   vs. 4

3rd round   
0   vs. 7
1   vs. 6
2   vs. 5
3   vs. 9
4   vs. 8


4th round   
6   vs. 0
5   vs. 1
9   vs. 2
8   vs. 3
7   vs. 4


5th round   
0   vs. 5
1   vs. 9
2   vs. 8
3   vs. 7
4   vs. 6
```

The method works fine until the $5^{th}$ round but not for any further rounds since it would imply that $0$ must play at home against a team from $1$ to $4$, which are supposed to play at home that round as well.

Is this mathematically possible? IF so, please show me how.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no solution (can you prove it?) if you arrange the matches as you have so that all teams play simultaneously. If you give some teams a "rest", the possibilities open up.

Comment: I cant tell whether its possible or not but if somebody can confirm it mathematically and let me know i will appreciate it.

Comment: :-) OK, it looks like you know the problem - you have the teams marching in step, one half "home-away" and the other half one "away-home". Someone has to break step....

Comment: So my problem is mathematically impossible to solve?

Comment: No - but you have imposed the constraint that all teams play every round, in which case it is.

Comment: Is there a defined name for this kind of problem/situation?

Comment: I don't know about a name for this particular problem, but if you had found a solution satisfying your constraints, you would have constructed a tournament (with some additional conditions), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29, where there is an arc going from team $A$ to team $B$ if $A$ visits $B.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

By way of illustration... here's how my solution starts

$$\begin{array} \\
1 & BvA & DvC & FvE & HvG & JvI \\
2 & AvD & CvF & EvH & GvJ &  \\
3 & DvB & FvA & HvC & JvE & IvG \\
4 & BvF & AvH & CvJ & EvI &  \\
5 & FvD & HvB & JvA & IvC & GvE \\
\end{array}$$

(it might be that my interest in bell-ringing is an advantage here :-) )

Comment: This solution can also be continued to produce a season where each team plays every other team twice; once home, once away.

Comment: But you had said it was not possible in your last comment and you were right. It doesnt make sense to me that 2 teams rest in the same round. That only happens when you have an odd number of teams since there will always be a team it cant be paired. But here we have an even number of teams so in your example, there is no point in letting B and I rest in the 2nd round since they will have to play each other at some point any way.

Comment: The point of resting B and I is to enable the home-away alternation, which would indeed eventually be impossible with 5 matches every match day, but is not impossible if you have 4 matches on some match days. You have decided that all teams play as often as possible, but that is not in the original problem statement, and that extra imposed requirement is what stops you.